# .htaccess if file exists rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I found a couple of similar questions, but it seems like i need your help, because i'm not able to write it on my own.

I want this: http://domain.com/folder/file.123.ext (should work also without 123)

to be rewritten to /folder/file.min.ext (if it exists)

or /folder/file.ext (if the minified version doesn't exist)

It's for my css and js files ... so it will load non-minified versions for those files that doesn't have ones.

I currently have this:

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.([0-9]+)\.(css|js)$ /$1/$2.min.$4
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.(css|js)$ /$1/$2.min.$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.min\.(css|js)$ /$1/$2.$3
```

it works fine when i remove the second line ... but i need it to work also without the number :(

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just replace the 2 rules with this?

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(\.[0-9]+)?\.(css|js)$ /$1/$2.min.$4
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Jon's answer, this should solve the redirect loop problem:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(\.[0-9]+)?\.(css|js)$ /$1/$2.min.$4

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.min\.(css|js)$ /$1/$2.$3
```

The first line will prevent the attached rule from being executed on redirect.

If you find any other issues or need to tweak this further, try using RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel (at level 5) to debug the rule set and find out exactly what mod_rewrite is doing.